# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 1

Tags: php, debugging

I know this error is due to some mismatched brackets, quotes or whatever, still I'm not able to find a solution since my code is working perfectly on localhost but giving me this error on my shared hosting server (same PHP version: 5.3.8)

```
function call_hook() {
    global $url;

    $url_array = explode('/', $url);

    if (isset($url_array[0]) && $url_array[0] != '') {
        $controller = $url_array[0];
    } else {
        $controller = DEFAULT_CONTROLLER;
    }

    if (isset($url_array[1]) && $url_array[1] != '') {
        $action = $url_array[1];
    } else {
        $action = DEFAULT_ACTION;
    }

    if (isset($url_array[2])) {
        $queryString = explode(PARAM_DELIMITER, $url_array[2]);
    } else {
        $queryString = array();
    }

    $controller_name = $controller;
    $controller = ucwords($controller);
    $model = rtrim($controller, 's');
    $controller .= 'Controller';
    $dispatch = new $controller($model, $controller_name, $action);

    if ((int)method_exists($controller, $action)) {
        // I get the error after this function call
        call_user_func_array(array($dispatch, $action), $queryString);
    } else {
        /* error */
    }
}
```

This function loads some parameters from the URL and then call the right controller, after the call_user_func_array call it should load the corresponding controller php file but I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /web/htdocs/www.mysite.com/home/app/application/controllers/CONTROLLERFILE.php on line 1
```

This happens with every controller.
I've tried to check the code preceding this call but since it's working fine on localhost I don't really know what to look about. The only difference I know of is that magic quotes are Off on localhost and On on the server but I don't know if this

**EDIT**
Also, the start of every controller is:

```
<?php
    class ControllerName extends Controller {
```

localhost is a Windows system my server is Linux one, if this could matter.

Comment: Demo: http://codepad.org/hkA9UTt7 Not getting a parse error with what you posted.

Comment: Confirmed parsing correctly for me too.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Try it yourself: http://www.dovemangiostasera.com/app/place/view/1

Comment: Pay special attention to the part *with what you posted*.

Comment: I think you need to show us the complete code of this controller (the path mentioned in the error message), at least the first 5 lines. What you posted does not reflect the first few actual lines (should start with `<?php`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it. Writing the code on Windows implied having `\r\n` as new line characters, which were not intepreted correctly on my Linux hosting: converting all `\r\n` to the UNIX standard new line char `\n` fixed the bug